# how to access time series programmaticaly?

Tags: r, statistics, time-series

I want to access part of a time series by using a *variable* that has the name of the desired object. So SPY.Close <- SPY[, 4] works fine, while

wanted="Close"; target=paste0("SPY",".",wanted); SPY[target] fails (please see below).

Edit 1: Wrote an index() function.

Code that seems to work.

```
library(quantmod)
index <- function(xs, x) {
  i = which(sapply(xs, function(y) x %in% y))
  rc <- if (length(i) == 0) 0 else i
}
tickers <- c("SPY")
getSymbols(tickers, from = "2007-01-01")
ns = names(SPY)
target = paste0("SPY",".","Close")
which(sapply(ns, function(y) target %in% y))
SPY.Close <- SPY[, i]
print(class(SPY.Close))
```

Original code that failed.

```
library(quantmod)
tickers <- c("SPY")
getSymbols(tickers, from = "2007-01-01")
print(typeof(SPY[, 4]))
print(class(SPY[, 4]))
print(names(SPY))
SPY.Close <- SPY[, 4]
print(typeof(SPY.Close))
print(class(SPY.Close))
wanted="Close"
target=paste0("SPY",".",wanted)
print(target)
SPY[target] # fails

> source("D:/ray/rapps/r/Monte Carlo Simulation/getdatabug.R")
[1] "double"
[1] "xts" "zoo"
[1] "SPY.Open"     "SPY.High"     "SPY.Low"     
[4] "SPY.Close"    "SPY.Volume"   "SPY.Adjusted"
[1] "double"
[1] "xts" "zoo"
[1] "SPY.Close"
[1] "SPY.Close"
Error in if (length(c(year, month, day, hour, min, sec)) == 6 && all(c(year,  : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In as_numeric(YYYY) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In as_numeric(MM) : NAs introduced by coercion
3: In as_numeric(DD) : NAs introduced by coercion
4: In as_numeric(YYYY) : NAs introduced by coercion
5: In as_numeric(MM) : NAs introduced by coercion
6: In as_numeric(DD) : NAs introduced by coercion
>
```

Comment: You can’t assign values to pasted strings. While technically you could use `assign()` to write to variables using character names but that’s kind of an R anti-pattern. Storing values in variable names only makes things more difficult later. In most cases it’s better to collect values in named lists.

Comment: maybe i can search the names and find the index. i will try that. thanks